# How to query which line I am configuring in a Cisco router?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

The Cisco router prompt shows only that I am configuring a line: config-line.

How can I make IOS to print exactly which line I am configuring?

Comment: It will be the line you entered to configure. Normally, you would configure all the VTY lines the same at the same time with the `line vty 0 15` command because you really have no idea to which line you will be connected. The other two are `line con 0`, and possibly `line aux 0` if you have a router, but you enter that before configuring the line so you already know which line you are configuring.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IOS does not show anything more than you're already seeing. You are expected to remember which line(s) you selected. Why would you be sitting in line configuration mode any longer than necessary to enter the desired line configuration commands? You can't end up in line config mode without specifying the line(s), so it really doesn't need to be in the prompt -- it'll be in you CLI history, and very likely still on your terminal screen.

Comment: OK but for almost anything there is a show command. Like pwd in Unix to show the current working directory.

Comment: There's no "show" commands in IOS configuration mode.